# Write a ublock filter rule for a parent element based on content of a child element

Tags: html, css, filter, css-selectors

I want to write a ublock filter to hide a list element that has a certain class and content, while I don't want to hide other list items that don't have this content:

class = "mp-Listing-priority"
content is "Topad"

This is the html code of the item that I want to hide.

```
<li class="mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item ">
    <a href="" class="mp-Listing-cover-link experimentStateC"></a>
    <figure class="mp-Listing-image-container"></figure>
    <div class="mp-Listing-content">
        <div class="mp-Listing-group mp-Listing-group--main"></div>
        <div class="mp-Listing-group mp-Listing-group--aside">
            <div class="mp-Listing-group mp-Listing-group--top-block"></div>
            <div class="mp-Listing-group mp-Listing-group--bottom-block">
                <span class="mp-Listing-priority">Topad</span>
                <span class="mp-Listing-seller-link">
                    <a href="https://.../" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" class="mp-TextLink ">Visit website</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

None of the examples below hide the list elements that I want to hide:

```
##li.mp-Listing--list-item[class="mp-Listing-priority"]
##li.mp-Listing--list-item["Topad"]
```

Comment: @Temani Afif, this is not about CSS directly, it's about uBlock! there you can select stuff based on content... please reconsider...

Comment: I think you could hide that with `www.domain.com##li.mp-Listing--list-item .mp-Listing-priority:has-text(Topad)` not the domain/target in front of the cosmetic filter though, I think uBlock ignores rules without a domain!

Comment: using     www.domain.com##li.mp-Listing--list-item .mp-Listing-priority:has-text(Topad)    hides the Topad text from each element in the list, instead of hiding the list element as requested.

Comment: what if you try `www.domain.com##li.mp-Listing--list-item:has-text(Topad)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

```
##li.mp-Listing--list-item:has-text(Topad)
```

Thank you exside

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will be useful to someone (*i myself, for example, often forget this syntax and always come across this page in searches*).

There is an extremely useful way to hide an element whose class contains certain characters.

```
##[class^="newsTicker_container"]
```

This tap is useful because many web applications today use CSS-modules that change class postfixes.